# How do I update the values in the table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do i actually update the values of table using PHP ? This code is not showing any error and its not updating either.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
die("couldn't connect" . $conn->connect_error());
}
echo ("connected successfully");
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$dept = $_POST['Department'];
$update = "update info set Name='$name', Department='$dept' where Id='$id'";
if($conn->query(update) === TRUE) {
echo ("Data updated successfully");
} 
else
{
echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: Have you checked the column names if they are correct? Is there a row matching with the bind `$id`? Did you execute your query? Show more code.

Comment: how you are executing your query in php ?

Comment: <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
 die("couldn't connect" . $conn->connect_error());
}
echo ("connected successfully");
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$dept = $_POST['Department'];
$update = "update info set Name='$name', Department='$dept' where Id='$id'";
if($conn->query(update) === TRUE) {
 echo ("Data updated successfully");
} else {
echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: Update this with your original post. Don't comment it.

Comment: Yes. The column names are perfect. I would've tried at least 10 times. I don't know what is the problem. i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Post this to your question and not here in the comment area.

Comment: First of all, are you sure the DB user you use to connect from php has the update privileges? - EDIT: seen your updated question. I think your root has all the privileges, even if it's not very safe to use it.

Comment: Sorry. And yes the privileges are fine. But can you people tell me how to check those? I may have a look now. I'm using XAMPP

Answer (score 4):

Hope this one help you!

```
$update = "update info set Name='".$name."', Department='".$dept."' where Id='".$id."'";
```

Comment: This doesn't really solves the problem of OP.

Answer (score 3):

Check this part of your code:

```
if($conn->query(update) === TRUE) {
```

where it should be:

```
if($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
```

- Make sure that you are using the correct credentials (*host, username, password, database name*) according to your MySQL database.
- Also your *table name* and *column name* should be correct which are being used in your query.
- Make sure that there is a match with your condition part of your query (`... WHERE Id='$id'`). Check it by running a query in your `PhpMyAdmin` page, or `Search` the ID, which is also the one you try to input in your form.
- Make sure that the name of the passed variables (`$_POST[]`) are correct.
- Be case sensitive.

Try changing your connection into:

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Other way to execute your query is to simply:

```
mysqli_query($conn,$update);
```

### Recommendation:

You should escape the values of your variables before using them into your query by using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["Name"]);
```

Or better, so you won't need to worry about binding variables into your query and as well prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), you should move to `mysqli_* prepared statement`:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE info SET Name=?, Department=? WHERE Id=?")){

  $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$_POST['Name'],$_POST['Department'],$_POST['Id']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? And I hope it's not because of downvote vengeance. Because I'm not the one that downvotes the answer of the other two.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't workout. Nor any other suggestions. What should i do now?

Comment: @NagaNaveen - execute your query by `mysqli_query($conn,$update);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$update = "update info set Name='".$name."', Department='".$dept."' where Id='".$id."'";
 mysql_query($update);
```

Comment: This doesn't really solves the problem of OP.

Comment: Please check your datatype in table ,  And could you please show your mysql error.

Comment: Umm.. I'm not the OP

Comment: The problem is, it is not showing any kind of error. When i enter the values in the respective fields and click on update, the values in the fields disappear. When i check in the table there are no changes.

Answer (score 1):

$update = "update info set Name='".$name."',set Department='".$dept."' where Id='".$id."'";

if this is not help please provide form code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(!$conn) 
{
die("ERROR CONNECTING TO DATABASE!");
}
echo "Connected Successfully";
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$dept = $_POST['Department'];
$update = "update info set Name='$name', Department='$dept' where Id='$id'";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$update);
if(!$qry) {
echo "Error Updating Details".mysqli_error($conn);
} 
else
{
echo "Data updated successfully";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

(Optional) Use secure things. Change to this for more secure.

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Id']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Name']);
$dept = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Department']);
```